# Not able to receive push notifaiction when I send it using fcm

Tags: push-notification, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I got the registration token from fcm but when I send Push Notification from FCM targeted single device entered the registration token and send it. I got no message on android simulator and fcm status failed.

Comment: Are you using Node server to send pushnotifications?

Answer (score 1):

Copy your google-service.json file to root folder (that contains www, config.xml etc).

Step 1:
Login to your firebase console.

[image]

Step 2:
On Project Overview Settings, Copy the **Cloud Messaging ServerKey**

My key ex:

```
`AAAAjXzVMKY:APA91bED4d53RX.....bla bla
```

Step 3:
Replace the key

```
define( "API_ACCESS_KEY", "My key");
```

Finally Test the app :D